# Accessibility: extending browser default focus styles to custom widgets

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, accessibility

We have a few accessible components which are created using `div`s/`span`s + aria properties. When these custom inputs / widgets get focus, we would like to show a focus state. We rely on browser default focus styles for that.

The problem is that browser default focus styles work with interactive elements like `button`, `a`, etc, but not with `div`, `span` by default.

Is there a way to extend browser default outline styles to these custom components ?

Things I have considered:

- override the default browser style, and define a custom focus style for everything
- figure out the browsers i want to support and somehow copy / recreate the existing focus styles and apply with browser prefix in the css

Comment: Have you considered changing your interactive `div` and `span` elements to `button`/`a`s?

Comment: some of them are composite widgets, which group multiple things together for a functionality. Consider a custom select for example, I can use the button for the select trigger, but on focus the outline would only be around the trigger while i would want it around the whole widget. wouldn't semantically make sense to wrap the whole widget in a button. Also, there are use cases where you have to programmatically focus a div for a11y, where we need these focus styles as well

Comment: This seems weird to me. Browser default focus styles apply to any element. Are you sure that your custom widgets are actually focusable? Do they have `tabindex="0"` set on them?

Comment: See [Firefox’s default CSS focus styles](https://github.com/sw4/revert.css/blob/master/revert_firefox.css#L485) and Chrome default focus styles](https://github.com/sw4/revert.css/blob/master/revert_webkit.css#L655). Firefox’ includes span and div, and Chrome does apply it’s focus style to any element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue lies elsewhere. Probably some of your stylesheets change the default browser outlines.

You can reset them to browser defaults by using [the CSS `revert` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert):

```css
/* some reset stylesheet might contain something like this */
span:focus, div:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/* which you can reset for your custom controls */
[role=button]:focus, [role=link]:focus {
  outline: revert;
}
```

```html
<!-- Use <button> wherever possible! -->
<div tabindex="0" role="button" onclick="" onkeydown="">Custom Button</div>

<!-- Use <a> instead, whenever possible! -->
<span tabindex="0" role="link" onclick="" onkeydown="">Custom Link</span>
```

I believe this is the case because browsers’ default CSS does style **any element’s focus**:

[Chrome’s Default Focus Styles](https://github.com/sw4/revert.css/blob/master/revert_webkit.css#L655)

```css
:focus { 
    outline: auto 5px -webkit-focus-ring-color
}
```

[Firefox’ Default Focus Styles](https://github.com/sw4/revert.css/blob/master/revert_firefox.css#L485)

```css
/* focusable content: anything w/ tabindex >=0 is focusable */
…, div:focus, …, span:focus {
  /* Don't specify the outline-color, we should always use initial value. */
   outline: 1px dotted;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the reason, my understanding was slightly flawed because of an override in the codebase.